# DL Query to get the Individual has object relation with given individual - not some (OWL)

Tags: ontology, owl, dlquery

Please explain how to get the set of individuals that has a relation ship the given set of individuals along some object property in DL query (not using the some quantifier)

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, improve it by: (1) explaining what's wrong with the `some` quantifier, (2) bringing an example of the concrete data that the query should deal with, (3) formulating the query in plain English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
object_property some ({ Individual1 } or ... or { IndividualN })
```

(Your question is hard to understand, so I'm guessing here.)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was help full.